# SOAP request with Zeep (Python)

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to send SOAP request using zeep module in python.
python -mzeep XXXXXXXX.wsdl
returns following:

Prefixes:

```
 xsd: http://www.AA.org/2003/XMLSchema
 ns0: http://www.bbbb.com/PM/BLS
```

Global elements:

```
 ns0:GetBalReq(header: ns0:RequestHeader, custId: xsd:string, customAvpList: ns0:AttributeValuePairList)
 ns0:GetBalResp(nalId: xsd:string, custId: xsd:string, custRole: xsd:string, nalType: xsd:string, bal: ns0:BalDetailsList, customAvpList: ns0:AttributeValuePairList)
```

Global types:

```
 xsd:anyType
 ns0:AttributeValuePair(attribute: xsd:string, value: xsd:string)
 ns0:AttributeValuePairList(item: ns0:AttributeValuePair[])
 ns0:BalDetailsList(item: ns0:BalDetails[])
 ns0:RequestHeader(auditInfo: xsd:string, transactionId: xsd:string)
 xsd:string
```

Bindings:

```
 Soap11Binding: {http://www.bbbb.com/PM/BLS}BLS
```

Service: BLS

```
 Port: BLS (Soap11Binding: {http://www.bbbb.com/PM/BLS}BLS)

     Operations:
        getBalReq(header: ns0:RequestHeader, custId: xsd:string, customAvpList: ns0:AttributeValuePairList) -> nalId: xsd:string, custId: xsd:string, custRole: xsd:string, nalType: xsd:string, bal: ns0:BalDetailsList, customAvpList: ns0:AttributeValuePairList
```

just by following:

```
from zeep import Client
client = Client('XXXXXXXX.wsdl')
client.service.getBalReq(custId='12345678')
```

I get following error:

```
"Missing element %s" % (self.name), path=render_path

zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element header (GetBalReq.header)
```

Now I have been breaking by brain for last 2 days how to make this work, how to send proper request in order to get valid response, read zeep documentation, forums etc etc but just can't figure it out. Any idea for proper code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter 'header' to the method 'getBalReq' as below.

```py
    from zeep import Client
    client = Client('XXXXXXXX.wsdl')

    header_request = client.get_type('ns0:RequestHeader')
    header = header_request(auditInfo = your_auditInfo,transactionId = your_transactionId)
    client.service.getBalReq(header=header, custId='12345678', customAvpList = your_customAvpList)
```

If customAvpList is an optional parameter, you can ignore it.